# Log4j2 not loading from external classpath in an EAR

Tags: spring, jboss, log4j, websphere, log4j2

The project artifact structure is:

```
test.ear
--lib - has all log4j2 jars core, web, bridge and JCL
--META-INF -- has app.xml, JBoss specific deployment XML, and manifest file 
--a.war -- each war has web.xml with log4jConfiguration and Log4jServletContextListener specified.
--b.war
--c.war
```

The war creates context with log4jConfiguration, which is "classpath:test.xml". I can see each war creating the context with log4jContextName I have provided in web.xml.I have a few crons, too, which run based on configured time intervals. When crons run, and many of the JMS process run, I observed the log files are not populated with logs(From project-specific classes). While going through the log4j2 code, I understood that log4j2 creates a context for each classloader. And in my case, it creates a context for "test.ear", which is defaulted to error(DefaultContext) as it is not able to find a default log4j2.xml since I have a custom named(test.xml) on in the classpath. The Log4jServletContextListener does not catch the "test.ear" event.

How to inject my "classpath:test.xml" while log4j2 creates a context for the ear file? Since my project can be both deployed to WebSphere and JBoss, I am looking forward to suggestions that are not server-specific. Or is there a way to create a single context for all the war and ear somehow? I have different apps outside this ear in same server so I cannot give an environmental config of -Dlog4j.configurationFile as other apps have there own log4j2 xml's.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I can think of is to place your log4j config file test.xml in a shared library and configure your application to use the shared library.

The following link describes how to configure a shared library for a server or an enterprise application on WebSphere.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-create-shared-library-and-associate-it-application-server-or-enterprise-application-websphere-application-server

The shared library should be a generic function for modern Java app servers, so JBoss should also be able to configure this.

Comment: the "test.xml" is already on the classpath. The problem is when Log4j2 creates a context for EAR, programatically there is no way to specify an XML in a shared folder with a different name other than log4j2.xml. If I put log4j2.xml it works but I want to load test.xml from the classpath.

Comment: Can you maybe post your log4j configuration in your web.xml? On log4j website, it has this line: "You must not manually configure the Log4jServletContextListener or Log4jServletFilter in your deployment descriptor (web.xml) or in another initializer or listener in a Servlet 3.0 or newer application unless you disable auto-initialization with isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled. Doing so will result in startup errors and unspecified erroneous behavior."

Comment: you are right. I have already that config in place for the wars. But there is no similar config that can be applied to the EAR level. ```<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jContextName</param-name>
        <param-value>AppName</param-value>
        <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:test.xml</param-value>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>```

Comment: I don't know if it's at all possible to have an EAR wide configuration then. The log4j website does not really explain this scenario in detail. For the need of context separation with other apps, maybe it's not really necessary to have a non-default log4j config filename.